# convert for loop to stdlib operations

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have the following code

```
for (i in 0..(sites.length()-1)) {
    val site = sites.getJSONObject(i)
    siteOptions.add(Site(site.getInt("id"), site.getString("name")))
}
```

Android studio suggest using stdlib operations. How do I do that?

Comment: It's not an answer to this question, but I think `getJSONObject` needs a `String` parameter, but in your code `i` is `Int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever an IDE suggests you to perform a transformation of your code, you do this by pressing Alt-Enter and selecting the necessary quickfix from the menu.

Answer (score 0):

It actually depends on the type of `sites`, which I expect to be `org.json.JSONArray`. You can apply a range and make use of functional methods like `map` then:

```
(0 until sites.length())
    .map { sites[it] }
    .forEach { siteOptions.add(Site(it.getInt("id"), it.getString("name")) }
```

AndroidStudio even gives you the option to convert it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `sites: JSONArray` and `siteOptions: MutableList<Site>` I'll do something like this with stdlib operations

```
siteOptions += (0 until sites.length())
        .mapNotNull { sites.optJSONObject(it) }
        .map { Site(it.getInt("id"), it.getString("name")) }
```

Less readeable but more memory efficient :

```
siteOptions += (0 until sites.length())
        .mapNotNull { sites.optJSONObject(it)
                ?.let { Site(it.getInt("id"), it.getString("name")) }
        }
```